# Why would fonts render differently between different versions of MacOS?

Tags: pdf, font

Recently, I purchased a new Mac and moved from 10.13 to 10.15 in the transition.  One thing that I have noticed is that my papers, which are PDFs, no longer render correctly.  The greek letters are all black boxes, such in the sniplet below where the omega from 50 Ohm has become a black box.

[image]

Any suggestions or guidance on how to return the Greeks would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install any fonts on the old system that are not on the new one? I would have a look in FontBook and see what is installed and if something is missing. If you didn't use Migration Assistant to transfer your stuff to the new Mac is is quite possible that you missed a font or two...

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using? Are the fonts properly embedded?

Comment: @MaxWyss These are all my papers from the IEEE.  It's 20 years of research, and the papers pass their embedded rules.  I think i'm going to delete the question and ask on tex.se.  This is just extremely weird as the paper is just Ariel

Comment: @bdegnan Ah, OK, the documents have been created with TeX (or similar). In any case, see that you can get your hands on Acrobat Pro, and look at the PDFs with that tool. I do have the suspicion that the fonts did not get embedded (and subset) properly. Although, the culprit could not be Arial, but the font used for the symbols (Arial could provide them, but they (the Omega character) could have been remapped onto a Symbol font)